# Moment JS: Get the date and time from the lost timezone string

Tags: javascript, datetime, format, timezone, momentjs

I have some formatted datetime string, like this `Fri Sep 18th 2020 05:52:20`.
When I use momentJS to convert theme to datetime => Fail. Because that's invalid datetime format.
So, how can I convert them to datetime with a timezone (ie: 'Euro/Paris').

Comment: If you want to parse a string as if it's for a particular timezone, you need to use a library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org) unless you want to write something yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date format isn't a standard format, you can specify a format string for it as the 2nd argument

(https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

The format string for: 3 letter day of week, 3 letter month, ordinal day, 4 digit year, 24 hour time format with leading 0 is:

```
ddd MMM Do YYYY HH:mm:ss
```

You can specify a timezone with `moment().tz`

```
moment.tz(
    moment(
        "Fri Sep 18th 2020 05:52:20",
        "ddd MMM Do YYYY HH:mm:ss"
    ), "Europe/Paris")
    .format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z"); // "2020-09-18 12:52:20 CEST"
```

Also please bear in mind RobG's comment on timezone

> the string is parsed as local, it's the output that is shifted to the specified timezone. So the resulting timestamp values are dependent on the host system timezone settings

Comment: Omg. I used `moment(dateString).format('ddd MMM Do YYYY HH:mm:ss')` instead of `moment(dateString, 'ddd MMM Do YYYY HH:mm:ss')`. That's cause my result is wrong. Thank you so much, you save my morning.

Comment: Note that the string is parsed as local, it's the output that is shifted to the specified timezone. So the resulting timestamp values are dependent on the host system timezone settings.

Comment: @DuyHưngAndrogyneTenor glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: @RobG thanks for clarifying! I've added it to the answer

Comment: If you want it parsed as being in the time zone provided, just remove the inner `moment` function.  In other words, `moment.tz(input, format, timezone)`.